# What is the most optimal way to draw arrows over matrix?

Tags: math-mode, nicematrix

[image]

I want to draw something similar to what is shown using `tikz` capabilities of `nicematrix`. Also, is it possible to control the spacing between comments and arrows tails?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{rules/color=[gray]{0.75}, hvlines}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    x
    & =
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[r]
        1 & 4 & 7
        \\
        2 & 5 & 8
        \\
        3 & 6 & 9
        \\
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{rules/color=[gray]{0.75}, hvlines}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    x
    & =
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[r]
        1 & 4 & 7
        \\
        2 & 5 & 8
        \\
        3 & 6 & 9
        \\
    \CodeAfter
       \begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw [->] (1-|2) -- (3-|4) ; 
       \node at ([yshift=1mm]1-|2) {\tiny\(k=+1\)} ;
       \draw [->] (2-|1) -- (4-|3) ; 
       \node at ([xshift=-0.7mm]2-|1) [rotate=90] {\tiny\(k=-1\)} ;
       \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Is is possible to get arrow heads as shown in the example image?

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh you can search on pgfmanual https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Triangle[length=3mm]}]
\draw[->] (0,0)--(3,2); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`